# Where can I find documentation when coding in Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Then writing XML as manifest, how can I find documentation for things like `intent-filter` or `action`? Can I somehow display information on this in Eclipse without visiting developer.android.com like I can see the JavaDoc in Eclipse?

```
<activity android:name=".Activity1"
android:label="Activity1">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse just press Ctrl+Space and you will get descriptions of elements.

Just make sure you're opening your manifest with the Manifest editor (right click on manifest -> open with -> Android Manifest Editor). Anyway why not use the GUI editor? You have tips there as well.

Comment: Thanks. is this same on mac? i am a newbie in android. 
So I tried to use editing source directly

Comment: @sandfox: Yes, it is the same on mac.

Answer (score 0):

A good start: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html